# Node Js NPM sharp. cannot write .gif to file

Tags: node.js, image, npm, buffer

I am currently making an image resizer for a website (it resizes an image based on the the width of the container it is in).

I can successfully save and server jpeg's and png's however i cannot seem to save .gif's to a file.

This code works for the jpg's and png's

```
    sharp(imgPath)
      .resize(containWidth, Null)
      .withoutEnlargement()
      .toFile(modImgPath, function(err) {
        if(err){console.log(err)}
      });
```

I can get the gif's to display in the browser (With the code below) however i cannot save them to file.

```
    sharp(imgPath)
      .resize(modImgPath, null)
      .withoutEnlargment()
      .toBuffer(function(err, outputBuffer) {
        if (err) {console.log(err)}
      }
```

Iv looked into how to save image buffers to file however nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the gif output seems to be unsupported in sharp.

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/162

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/245

One solution, though I haven't tried to see if it works, is to change the output to another format. This will save the first frame of your gif.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, GIF output is not supported by sharp (or libvips). The use of PNG output for GIF input is probably the most suitable choice of format. The `toFormat` method is your friend.